# The conditional expectation of exp(XY) given Y

Tags: stochastic-calculus

$ X \sim N(0;\sigma^2) $ and Y is a random variable that is independent of X.
How do I compute $ \mathbb{E}[e^{XY}|Y] $ ?

Comment: How do you get from $ E[e^{XY}|Y] $ to $ e^YE[e^X] $ ? You can't isolate Y from X like you did because it's not a sum. It's $ e^{XY} $ not $ e^Xe^Y $.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. Then it just  $ E[e^{XY}|Y=y]=E[e^{yX}]$ this is just  moment generating function of $X$ evaluated at $y$.

Comment: I don't know what a moment generating function is. Is there a way to just compute that conditional expectation without doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$ and $g(y)=E[f(X,y)]$. By the [Independence Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/845387/136641),
$$
E[f(X,Y)|Y]=g(Y).
$$
So let's compute $g(y)$:
$$
g(y)=E[f(X,y)]=E[e^{yX}]=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2y^2)
$$
where we have noted $E[e^{yX}]$ is just the moment generating function of $X$ evaluated at $y$. The final answer is then $g(Y)=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2Y^2)$.

---

To derive $E[e^{yX}]$ note that
\begin{align*}
E[e^{yX}]&=\int(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp(yx)\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})dx\\
&=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2y^2)\int(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp(-\frac{(x-y\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2})dx\\
&=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2y^2).
\end{align*}
The integral in the second line evaluates to $1$ because $x\mapsto(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp(-\frac{(x-y\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2})$ is the density function of $N(y\sigma^2,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: The rest is clear. But I'm having a problem understanding why $ E[f(X,Y)|Y]=g(Y) $ or $ E[e^{XY}|Y]= E[e^{XY}]  $. X is independent of Y so it would make sense for me to say $ E[e^{X}|Y]= E[e^{X}]  $ because $ e^X $ is independent of $Y$. But is $ e^{XY} $ independent of Y?

Comment: @SidiAli I don't think I implied anywhere that $e^{XY}$ is independent of $Y$. Where did you see it?

Comment: You didn't say that. But I'm assuming that you can't say that $ E[Z|Y]=E[Z] $ unless Z is independent of Y. So why is $ E[e^{XY}|Y]=E[e^{XY}] $ if $ e^{XY} $ is not independent of $Y$ ?

Comment: @SidiAli I never claimed $E[e^{XY}|Y]=E[e^{XY}]$ either. $E[e^{XY}]$ is nonrandom whereas the answer for $E[e^{XY}|Y]$ I gave you is $g(Y)$ is random because it is a function of $Y$. I suggest you read the linked thread about the Independence Lemma (the statement at least) carefully.