# Proof of van Handel "Probability in High Dimension" Theorem 2.3

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question about the proof of Theorem 2.3 in van Handel's [Probability in High Dimension](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ervan/APC550) (page 15). At the bottom of page 15, the book writes $$E[E[f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\mid X_1,\dots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\dots,X_n]\mid X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}]=E[E[f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\mid X_1,\dots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\dots,X_n]\mid X_1,\dots,X_{k}]$$ where $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent. I was unable to understand why this is true. Thank you!

Comment: What you need is Independent Lemma.

Comment: I proved it long time ago in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845387/independence-lemma-is-it-non-trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$
be indpendent random variables. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be a bounded Borel function (Note that boundedness can be relaxed.
Here, we impose this condition so that conditional expectation makes
sense). Fix an integer $k$ with $1<k<n$. Let $\mathcal{G}_{1}=\sigma(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{n})$.
Observe that $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are
$\mathcal{G}_{1}$-measurable while $X_{k}$ and $\mathcal{G}_{1}$
are independent. Therefore, Independent Lemma is applicable. Define
a Borel function $\varphi_{1}:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $\varphi_{1}(x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{n})=E\left[f(x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1},X_{k},x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{n})\right]$.
By Independent Lemma, we have that $E\left[f(X_{1},\ldots,X_{n})\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}\right]=\varphi_{1}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{n})$.

Let $\mathcal{G}_{2}=\sigma(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{k})$. Note that
$X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{k-1}$ are $\mathcal{G}_{2}$-measurable while
$X_{k+1},X_{k+2},\ldots,X_{n}$ and $\mathcal{G}_{2}$ are independent.
Define a Borel function $\varphi_{2}:\mathbb{R}^{k-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $\varphi_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{k-1})=E\left[\varphi_{1}(x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1},X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{n})\right].$
By Independent Lemma, we have that $E\left[\varphi_{1}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{n})\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right]=\varphi_{2}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1})$.

Let $\mathcal{G}_{3}=\sigma(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{k-1})$. Clearly
$\mathcal{G}_{3}\subseteq\mathcal{G}_{2}$.
Denote $Y=f(X_{1},\ldots,X_{n})$. By tower property of conditional
expectation, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{3}\right]\\
 & = & E\left[E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right]\mid\mathcal{G}_{3}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}
However,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right]\\
 & = & E\left[\varphi_{1}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1},X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{n})\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right]\\
 & = & \varphi_{2}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1}),
\end{eqnarray*}
which is $\mathcal{G}_{3}$-measurable. Taking $\mathcal{G}_{3}$-conditional
expectation on both sides yields $E\left[E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right]\mid\mathcal{G}_{3}\right]=\varphi_{2}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1}).$

Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{3}\right]\\
 & = & E\left[E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right]\mid\mathcal{G}_{3}\right]\\
 & = & \varphi_{2}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k-1})\\
 & = & E\left[E[Y\mid\mathcal{G}_{1}]\mid\mathcal{G}_{2}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Sorry, why do we have $\mathcal{G}_2\subseteq \mathcal{G}_1$? It seems to me that $\mathcal{G}_1$ doesn't have the information of $X_k$.

Comment: Sorry. A typo. Let me correct it.

Comment: Actually, we only need $\mathcal{G}_3 \subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$.